# How to do a for loop in the naive Bayes classification model in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, classification, naivebayes

These are my codes for the naive bayes. I would like to loop through the dataframes to print out most informative words for different categories.

```
def NB_func():
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['content'], df['cat_id'], random_state=0)
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
    clf_NB = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)
    print(clf_NB)

    # save the model to disk
    filename = '../dataanalysis/models/Naive_Bayes.sav'
    pickle.dump(clf_NB, open(filename, 'wb'))

    print()
    '''Print the prediction of the category from the unknown document'''
    # For now its not accurate due to insufficient sample data
    # print("NAIVE BAYES CLASSIFIER: ", clf_NB.predict(count_vect.transform([""])))
    print()

    print("===============================================")
    print("================= NAIVE BAYES =================")
    print("===============================================")
    most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(tfidf, clf_NB, n=10)
```

The output after running the NB_func() method  (the numbers 3 and 4 are the categories):

```
===============================================
================= NAIVE BAYES =================
===============================================
3 -7.788372938139329 abato
3 -7.788372938139329 abdome abdome erythema
3 -7.788372938139329 abdome erythema redness
3 -7.788372938139329 abdomen distended complaint
3 -7.788372938139329 abdomen ex drain
3 -7.788372938139329 abdomen hbs
3 -7.788372938139329 abdomen hbs kidneys
3 -7.788372938139329 abdomen insitu
3 -7.788372938139329 abdomen insitu pinkish
3 -7.788372938139329 abdomen pelvis

4 -6.221523090721391 bloods operationprocedure
4 -6.4003419545043165 absence peripheral oedema
4 -6.5928517017851505 assessmentreassessment indicated indian
4 -6.677711285491995 afternnon cardiovascular presence
4 -6.698249643881156 bread resting
4 -6.781485612022626 assessmentreassessment indicated braden
4 -6.784706622916945 bardia ordered
4 -6.785386746502815 access lips inspect
4 -6.7946948984778395 alzheimers disease gcs
4 -6.849375428834153 alarmdate cohort
```

The output above only shows categories 3 and 4. How do I do a for loop in 
this classification model such that everytime I run the program it shows me 
different categories instead of just the two of them? For instance, program running the first time will show category 3 and 4, second time will show 4 and 5 and so on.

Below is the most informative method:

```
def most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(vectorizer, classifier, n=100):
    """
    Identify most important features if given a vectorizer and binary classifier. Set n to the number
    of weighted features you would like to show.
    """
    # additional stopwords to be remove
    # Open a file and read it into memory
    file = open('..\stopwords.txt')
    additional_stopwords = file.read()
    additional_stopwords = additional_stopwords.split()

    class_labels = classifier.classes_
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
    feature_names = [word for word in feature_names if word not in additional_stopwords]

    topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[:n]
    topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[-n:]

    # class_labels = category
    # coef = co-effecient
    # feat = most informative feature
    for coef, feat in topn_class1:
        print(class_labels[0], coef, feat)

    print()

    for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
        print(class_labels[1], coef, feat)
```

Comment: It seems like you need to edit, and we need to see, `most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification`.

Comment: @DavisHerring I have already provided the most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification

Comment: @DavisHerring please do take a look, thanks :((

Comment: I’m no expert in this: I just said to provide more code because it might help anyone answer.  But if you’re doing *binary* classification, how do you expect to have more than two classes?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.